# Accountlist needs to be displayed on a jsp in table format

Tags: java

I have a displayaccount jsp which needs to get the customer object out of the session which i did, and the customer object has the accountlist that i created and i did the scriptlet tags for displaying a table, but the "aList" is in read and says cannot find symbol

ive tried aArray, aList both are in read for some reason

Code for AccountList:

```
public class Accountlist {
   int count = 0;
   private final Account aArray[] = new Account[10];



    public void addAccount(Account a1)
    {

        aArray[count] = a1;
        count++;
    }
    public void display(){
       System.out.println("         "+count+" Accounts Found");

        for(int i=0; i<count;  i++) {   
         aArray[i].display();
        }  
   }  

     public static void main(String args[]) {

        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.selectDB("3001");
        c1.display();

}
}
```

code for customer java business obvject :

```
public class Customer {
    String CustID;
    String CustPassword;
    String CustFirstName;
    String CustLastName;
    String CustAddress;
    String CustEmail;

   public Accountlist aList = new Accountlist();
public void display() {
 public void getAccounts()  {
         try {
            //Load Driver
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
             //Create statement and sql
             try ( //Create statement and sql
                     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+url)) {
                 //Create statement and sql
                 Statement st = con.createStatement();
                 String sql = "SELECT AcctNo from Accounts WHERE Cid = '" + CustID + "'";
                 Account a1;
                 String an;
                 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                 while (rs.next()) {                    
                    a1=new Account(); 
                     an=rs.getString("AcctNo");
                     a1 = new Account();
                     a1.selectDB(an);
                     aList.addAccount(a1);
                 }
                 //Close Connection
             }
         } 
                     catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException x) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                             }
                    }

        aList.display();
}
```

heres my current display account jsp :

```
<%@page import="Business.Customer"%>
   <head>
      <title>Account Summary</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>

       <% 
           Customer c1 = (Customer)session.getAttribute("c1");
           %>
      <h1 align="center"> SUMMARY</h1>
      <br>
      </br>
      <form>
         <div>
<%
                if(!c1.aList.aArray[0].getAcctNo().equals("")) {
                    out.println("<table>");
                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<th>AcctNoe</th>");
                    out.println("<th>Cid</th>");
                    out.println("<th>Type</th>");
                    out.println("<th>Balance</th>");
                    for(int i=0; i<c1.aList.count; i++) {
                        out.println("<tr>");
                        out.println("<td>"+c1.aList.aArray[0].getAcctNo()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td>"+c1.aList.aArray[0].getCid()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td>"+c1.aList.aArray[0].getType()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td>"+c1.aList.aArray[0].getBalance()+"</td>");
                        out.println("</tr>");
                    }
                    out.println("</tr>");
                    out.println("</table>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("No Accounts found<br>");
                }
            %>

         </div>
         <div>
         <input type="submit" name="subBtn" value="lookup"/>

         <input type="reset" name="rstBtn" value="clear"/>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does 'Customer' class compile?

Comment: YEAH I didnt include al lthe code of the custoemr class but wen i run the file it does display the acounts like the following: ========Display=======
AcctNo    :90001
Cid       :3003
Type       :CHK
Balance   :786.5400
========Display=======
AcctNo    :90010
Cid       :3003
Type       :MMA
Balance   :10000.0000

Comment: Also place the code where you store 'customer' object in session.

Comment: how does it look im prety sure its in acoutlookupservlet